# How to Enumerate ALL SharePoint MOSS databases

Tags: 2007, infrastructure, database

I want to enumerate all databases used by my SharePoint 2007 system. The stsadm -o enumcontentdbs only handles content db's but I also want the names of the SSP, Search and any other databases used by in the system.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself. [See my blog entry](http://www.theodells.org/theodells/blog/2010/07/locating-all-sharepoint-2007-databases/).

## Excerpt

> Central Admin >> OPERATIONS >> PERFORM A BACKUP (which takes you to “/_admin/Backup.aspx”)
>
> This page provides you a list of all items that are (or should be) backed up by MOSS. Lo and behold, there are ALL the databases listed! Alas, it also lists other things than the DBs, but it’s nice enough to tell you what each item is. Brilliant tip. Thanks, Phread!

Ref: [How to List all SharePoint Databases](http://mnteractive.com/archive/how-to-list-all-sharepoint-databases/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this SQL query on the server, but it will of course get everything, not just SharePoint databases.

SELECT name FROM sys.databases

Comment: This is where good DB naming conventions can help you e.g. SharePoint_ContentDBNameOrPurpose. Then you can put that in your SELECT

Comment: agreed but I don't have that luxury which is why I need an alternate, reliable approach.

Comment: Thanks but that is not the meaning of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before now:
http://spsfarmreport.codeplex.com/

Gives you a good report of the farm and will give you apps and associated content DB